# Unity debug и profiler не работают если запускать билд на телефоне

Tags: unity3d, отладка

Запускаю через Build and run.  Все нужные галочки стоят:

- Development build
- Autoconnect profiling
- scripts debugging

При этом профайлер ничего не показывает, а дебаггинг невозможен(брейкпоинты игнорируются). В стандартном режиме запуска и профайлер и дебаггинг работают нормально.

Что уже сделал/пробовал:

- На самом телефоне дебаггинг включен(стоят галочки "stay awake", "USB debugging", "Install via USB", "USB Debugging(Security settings)")
- ADB драйвер телефона(Xiaomi Redmi x4) на винду установлен
- Телефон подключен через кабель, а не по WiFi
- ADB сам телефон видит:

  `C:\Users\UKS2\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools> adb devices
  List of devices attached
  a616d3d10204    device`
- "Revoke USB Debugging Access" так же пробовал нажимать.
- Компьютер перезапускал уже несколько раз. В том числе и после ревока.
- Телефон так же перезапускал. В том числе и после ревока.

Дополнительная информация:

- результат "adb logcat -s Unity" с консоли показывает лог действий на телефоне. Но при этом эти действия все равно не отображаются в самом юнити.
- В VS: Debug-> Attach Unity Debugger показывает только инстанс локального компьютера. Не уверен так ли это должно быть.
- Если подключится по вайфаю(а не кабелем) и вручную указать айпишник профайлеру, то профайлер начинает работать. То есть сам конекшн работает. Но при этом юнити почему-то пытается читать дебаг-информацию из левого места.

Comment: а в настройках профайлера пробовали IP для соединения поменять?

Comment: @Xumera_hZ попробовал подключится по вайфаю и изменить настройки. Профайлер подключился. Если вручную выставить и на консоль айпишник, то тоже работает. Но дебаг так и не смог выкрутить. Что делать и в какие настройки лезть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ оказался банальным. Фаерволл. Я все это время думал что он вырублен.